# Checking if there is a certain string in an object contained in an ArrayList, then adding the object to another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have `Arraylist` of objects `ArrayList<Product> productDatabase.` The object contains a `String` and a `double` and then these objects will be added to the productDatabase by `addProductToDatabase();` as follows:

```
public void addProductToDatabase(String productName, double dimensions); {
    Product newProduct = new Product(ProductName, dimensions);
    productDatabase.add(newProduct);
}
```

I also want to make an `Arraylist<ProductCount> productInventory` which counts how many `Product` are accounted for. Before it can add to `ArrayList<ProductCount> productInventory` however, it should first check if the object details exist in the productDatabase while running `addProductToInventory()`

```
public Product getProduct(String name) {
    for(i = 0; i < productDatabase.size(); i++)
    if(productDatabase.get(i).contains(name) //Error: cannot find symbol- method contains.(java.lang.String)
        return productDatabase.get(i)
}

public void addProductToInventory(String productName, double quantity)
{
    Product p = getProduct(name);        
    productCount.add(new ProductCount(o, quantity)); 
}
```

Assume that you always have different objects (so nothing will have the same name), but you're always unsure of the dimensions (so when you input the same `producttName` + dimensions you edit the dimensions in it).

At the end of the day, you have to put all the items in it a large box and report what you've inventoried, so you also have a `getProductQuantityTotal()` and you have to `getProductDimensionTotal()`-- as the name suggests, get the total of number of objects you've counted, and the sum of the dimensions.

What do I have to add/change/remove about this code? Don't consider syntax first (because BlueJ checks for common syntax errors and I just typed this by hand). I'm sure that I'm missing a `for` statement somewhere, and I'm probably misusing `contains()` because it won't recognise it (I have `import java.util.*;` and `import java.util.ArrayList;`)

Comment: I recommend not naming your class `Object` because it will be confused with `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: I wish you would boil this down. There's a lot of information here, and I'm thinking the question you really need answered might be much simpler.

Comment: There's a lot to take in, and valid syntax first would be a more appropriate starting point.

Comment: @PaulBellora it's not actually object in the code that I'm using; I was just using it as an example. I've changed it to `Product`, now, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @aliteralmind the main question is the question that's on the title bar. I just added some more code because maybe I've left something out. The bottom questions are follow-up questions / suggestions

Comment: Do you have to use a list? Can you use a map?

Comment: @aliteralmind Yes, I have to use a list-- it was required by my professor.

Comment: The object called `Product` probably has a method which will tell you what the product's name is.  Use that instead of `contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your post title: How to find a string *in an object*, for a list of those objects, here is some sample code that does this:

First, I created a trivial object that has a string field:

```
class ObjectWithStringField  {
   private final String s;
   public ObjectWithStringField(String s)  {
      this.s = s;
   }
   public String getString()  {
      return  s;
   }
}
```

And then a code that populates a list of it, and then searches each for the string. There's no magic here, it just iterates through the list until a match is found.

```
import  java.util.List;
import  java.util.Arrays;

/**
   <P>{@code java StringInObjectInList}</P>
 **/
public class StringInObjectInList  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      ObjectWithStringField[] owStrArr = new ObjectWithStringField[]  {
         new ObjectWithStringField("abc"),
         new ObjectWithStringField("def"),
         new ObjectWithStringField("ghi")};

      //Yes this is a List instead of an ArrayList, but you can easily 
      //change this to work with an ArrayList. I'll leave that to you  :)
      List<ObjectWithStringField> objWStrList = Arrays.asList(owStrArr);

      System.out.println("abc? " + doesStringInObjExistInList("abc", objWStrList));
      System.out.println("abcd? " + doesStringInObjExistInList("abcd", objWStrList));
   }
   private static final boolean doesStringInObjExistInList(String str_toFind, List<ObjectWithStringField> owStrList_toSearch)  {
      for(ObjectWithStringField owStr : owStrList_toSearch)  {
         if(owStr.getString().equals(str_toFind))  {
            return  true;
         }
      }
      return  false;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java StringInObjectInList
abc? true
abcd? false
```

In the real world, instead of a `List`, I'd use a `Map<String,ObjectWithStringField>`, where the key *is* that field. Then it'd be as simple as `themap.containsKey("abc");`. But here it is implemented as you require. You'll still have quite a bit of work to do, to get this working as specifically required by your assignment, but it should get you off to a good start. Good luck!